# Using jQuery to change div from position:fixed to relative based on window scroll

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to create a series of DIVs that become fixed at certain points during page scroll.
I'm trying to do something similar to this:
http://www.girlfriendnyc.com/#/portfolio/redsquareagency

Scroll down and you'll see what I'm talking about.

Does anyone know of a plugin that already has this functionality or have any tips to get me started? I'm pretty good with jQuery, just not totally sure what path to take with this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This one is pretty great, because it's event-based rather than having to check positions or anything. (See the sticky elements example for what you wanted)

http://imakewebthings.github.com/jquery-waypoints/